# How do I test a Sinatra Server-Sent Events application?

Tags: unit-testing, sinatra, server-sent-events

I'm building a small chat application to understand how it streams work with Sinatra. It's supposed to be a really simple application and, meant only for sending and receiving messages.

This is what I have so far:
    require 'sinatra'
    require 'json'

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  enable :logging
  set :server, :thin
  set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/assets'

  connections = []

  get '/chat' do
    erb :chat
  end

  get '/stream' do
    content_type "text/event-stream"
    stream(:keep_open) do |out|
      connections << out
      connections.reject!(&:closed?)
    end
  end

  post '/:message' do
    connections.each do |out|
      out << params['message'] << "\n"
      out.close
    end

    "message received"
  end
end
```

And:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../app'
require 'pry'

RSpec.describe 'ChatServer' do
  def app
    App
  end

  it 'asserts true' do
    expect(true).to eq(true)
  end

  it 'posts message' do
    post '/message'
    expect(last_response.body).to eq('message received')
    expect(last_response.status).to eq(200)
  end

  it 'gets stream with correct content type' do
    get '/stream'
    expect(last_response.headers['Content-Type']).to include('event-stream')
  end

end
```

My question is how do I unit test scenarios like

- client subscribes on get `/stream`
- post `/message` sends 'message' to
  subscribers

Thanks in advance!